# Configure access for using this component with a permission not available in drupal settings?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-rules

I have created a new rules component action set for a view that shows user of a certain role. The action set displays a system message and sends an email to the admin when executed. The view shows the bulk operations for user 1 (admin) and executes the action set for user 1, however it does not do these for any other role on the site.

I went through and checked all the permissions and in order for a role to use the bulk operations they must have the "Administer site configuration" permission checked, which has security implications.

I cannot "Configure access for using this component with a permission" as suggested here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/what-limits-the-options-in-a-bulk-operations-menu-beyond-their-initial-settings

When I try to see the "Settings" related to my action set there is nothing available?

I have content access module installed and actions permissions (VBO) module installed. I have tried disabling them both to view settings on the rule action set and nothing changes. Do I have to grant the permission "Administer site configuration" to other roles for them to use this view?

Answer (score 1):

The "*Configure access for using this component with a permission*" that you are looking for, is a checkbox that needs to be turned on. It is located within the "**Settings**"" drop-down menu inside your actual Rules component.

These are the steps to actually "find" those settings:

- Navigate to `/admin/config/workflow/rules/components` within your site.
- Select the **Edit** link to the right of your actual Rules component.
- Expand the **Settings** drop-down menu.
- Near the bottom of the expanded settings box you should see what you're looking for. Enable the option, and specify the appropriate "roles".